# Initializing a class's vector of shared pointers in a constructor to a vector

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I create a vector of `int` type called `x` in `main`, and then want to my instance of class `A` called `a` to initialize its vector of shared pointers `x_vec` to `x`. I can successfully initialize the shared pointers if I pass the vector `x` by reference or by value, but if I pass the vector `x` as a pointer (so that if `x` changes, so does `x_vec`), then I receive the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

My code:

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class A{

private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> x_vec;

public:
  A(std::vector<int>* a_val){
    std::cout << "Creating A instance with a vec = ";
    for(int i = 0; i < a_val->size(); ++i){

      x_vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int> (a_val[i])); //offending line
      std::cout << *x_vec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  };
};

int main()
{
  // define vector called x
  std::vector<int> x;
  // number of ints in x
  int n_x = 5;
  // fill x
  for(int nx = 0; nx < n_x; ++nx){
    x.push_back(nx);
    std::cout << "x " << nx << " is " << x[nx] << std::endl;
  }
  // create instance of A
  A a(&x);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help and patience with my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
A(std::vector<int>* a_val)
```

`a_val` is passed in as a pointer. That means in

```
x_vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int> (a_val[i]));
```

`a_val[i]` is indexing the pointer `a_val`, not the `vector` it points at, resulting in elements that are `std::vector<int>`s not `int`s.

You could

```
x_vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int> ((*a_val)[i]));
```

and dereference the pointer to get `vector`'s `operator []` instead of the pointers, but the right way to fix this is ...

## Solution: Don't pass in a pointer. Use a reference

```
A(std::vector<int> & a_val)
```

And since it's only being read, a `const` reference is probably in order to provide acceptance of constant and temporary variables.

```
A(const std::vector<int> & a_val)
```

Invoke with

```
A a(x);
```

instead of

```
A a(&x);
```

## Edit:

Missed another bit of back-splash:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a_val->size(); ++i)
```

needs to become

```
for (int i = 0; i < a_val.size(); ++i)
```

because a_val's not a pointer anymore and probably should be

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < a_val.size(); ++i)
```

because `size()` doesn't return an `int`

When you remove the debugging statements consider turning this into a range-based for loop.

```
for (const auto & val : a_val)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the pass-by-reference working previously. I am interested in ensuring that class ```A```'s pointer vec keeps track of changes in the ```x``` vector. Is this possible? That is, if I redefine ```x``` after initialising ```A```, what is the best way for the instance of ```A``` to update it's ```x_vec```? I thought this was the value of passing something by a pointer?

Comment: A pointer is a type of reference. The best way to link `A` with `x` is to store a suitable reference to `x`, not the elements of `x`, inside `A`. Shared pointer is useless unless both are shared pointer (otherwise they're not sharing). What you currently have stores shared pointers that are copies of the values in `x`. What you may need is a `shared_ptr<vector<int>> x`. Hard to say for sure without more information. This is radically different from the question you asked, so I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: reference in the C++ context of `A & a` (`a` is a references to an `A`) is different from the concept (and I also need to be careful about how I use [concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) soon) of a reference. The former is an implementation of the latter. A c++ reference is a reference. A pointer is also a reference.